# Angular controller is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, dom-events

I want to create some event handler in my directive's controller. Here is directive code:

```
module.exports = function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        bindToController: true,
        scope: {
           myarticle: '=article'
        },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        templateUrl: '../../views/draggableArticle.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        },
        controller: function() {
            this.clicked = function() {
                alert('clicked');
            };
            this.dragstartHandler = function() {
                alert('draged');
           };
        }
    };
 };
```

And my view:

```
<div draggable="true" ondragstart="ctrl.dragstartHandler($event);" ng-click="ctrl.clicked()">
    <h2>{{ctrl.myarticle.webTitle | limitTo: 40}}</h2>
    <p>{{ctrl.myarticle.blocks.body[0].bodyTextSummary | limitTo: 200}}</p>
</div>
```

When I click on the block it works and alert "clicked", but when I drag a block it gives me an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ctrl is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ondragstart* is native JS event fired from within global *window* scope, which is not aware of needed controller, while *ng-click* is fired from within controller's scope. We can load needed scope using `angular.element(this).scope()` function:

```
<div draggable="true" 
     ondragstart="angular.element(this).scope().ctrl.dragstartHandler();" 
     ng-click="ctrl.clicked()">
  <h2>{{ctrl.myarticle.webTitle | limitTo: 40}}</h2>
  <p>{{ctrl.myarticle.blocks.body[0].bodyTextSummary | limitTo: 200}}</p>
</div>
```

for the same reason angular $event is also unavailable, but you can still use all arguments passed to native function.

There is also angular module *ngDraggable* https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable, but it has an issue with firing drag start event - https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable/issues/89